# jQuery does not send form even when file is uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a function to validate if an file is uploaded or not.
When the file is not uploaded the form should not submit, but when a file is uploaded it should submit.

But when I upload a file I still get the error that I have to upload a file.

Here is the jQuery code I am using:

```
$("#btnSave").click(function () {      
    var vidFileLength = $("#videoUploadFile")[0].files.length;
    if(vidFileLength === 0){
        $("#formType").submit(function(e){
        alert('Selecteer een afbeelding!');
        e.preventDefault();
        });
    }
});
```

And here is the form:

```
<form action="php/edit.php?id=type" method="post" id="formType">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Website bewerken</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="form-group">
            <label>Type ID</label>
            <input type="text" id="typeId" name="typeid" class="form-control" readonly="readonly">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Type Naam</label>
            <input type="text" id="typeNaam" name="typenaam" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Type Waarde</label>
            <input type="text" id="typeWaarde" name="typewaarde" class="form-control" >
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Type Afbeelding</label>
            <input class="input-group" type="file" id="videoUploadFile" name="user_image" accept="image/*" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" id="btnSave" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because you've added the `submit` event handler in the `if` condition, therefore once the form is made valid again the old submit handler will stop the submission.

To fix this you need to change your logic to always execute on the `submit` handler and use `preventDefault()` to stop the submission if the file is not present. Try this:

```
$('#formType').submit(function(e) {
  var vidFileLength = $("#videoUploadFile")[0].files.length;
  if (vidFileLength === 0) {
    alert('Selecteer een afbeelding!');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```